# Bigquery, how to count events group by week?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I just started working with Bigquery. Data comes from firebase and I noticed that I got the data each day, for example `gara-e78a5.analytics_247657392.events_20221231`, `gara-e78a5.analytics_247657392.events_20221230` etc....

Each row comes with an `event_date` like under this format `20221231`

I want to count the number of people landing on our page each week, but I don't know I to group them by week.

I started something like this but I don't know to group it by week:

```
SELECT count(event_name) FROM app-xxxx.analytics_247657392.events_* where event_name = 'page_download_view' group by
```

Thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 2):

You can use the WEEK (or ISOWEEK) function.

> WEEK: Returns the week number of the date in the range [0, 53]

More: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/date_functions

Formats - https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/timestamp_functions#format_timestamp

This should work

```
select EXTRACT(ISOWEEK FROM(CAST(PARSE_DATE('%Y%m%d', <column>) as TIMESTAMP))) as week_of_year from <table>
```

Output

[image: Output]

Comment: i got an error `Syntax error: Unexpected ")" at [1:50]` but i don't know why, even I added a ')', the error is still there.

Comment: Thanks, I'll fix it and update once I get the console.

Comment: @TeddyKossoko Fixed, if helped do accept the answer :)

Answer (score 1):

Based on @Ronak, i found the solution.

```
SELECT week_of_year, sum(nb_download) as nb_download_per_week from (
SELECT DISTINCT EXTRACT (WEEK from (PARSE_DATE('%Y%m%d', event_date))) as week_of_year, count(event_name) as nb_download from `tabllle-e78a5.analytics_XXXXX.events_*` where event_name =    'landing_event_download_apk'  group by event_date) group by week_of_year
```